# Stay logged using Next 13

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js, cookies, next.js13

When I log in, it logs in normally, takes the user data, the cookie, everything is fine, 100%. However, when I update the page for example, it loses the user data, so as a result, I either log out or, if I comment out the signOut line, it ends up with user undefined. That's just my problem, I just wanted to stay logged in, make my Cookie (I'm using the Nookies lib) continue to "hold" the user. The repo link is available for everyone to access, my AuthContext.tsx is this:

```
 "use client"

import { ReactNode, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { api } from '../services/apiClient'
import { destroyCookie, setCookie, parseCookies } from 'nookies'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { toast } from "react-toastify"

type UserProps = {
  id: string
  name: string
  email: string
  role: string
}

type SignInProps = {
  email: string
  password: string
}

type AuthContextData = {
  user: UserProps
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  signIn: (credentials: SignInProps) => Promise<void>
  signOut: () => Promise<void>
}

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode
}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextData)

export function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserProps>()
  const isAuthenticated = !!user
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const { '@proposalsmayarabecker.token' : token } = parseCookies()

    if (token) {
      api.get('/user').then(response => {
        const { id, name, email, role } = response.data

        setUser({ id, name, email, role })
      }).catch(() => {
        signOut()
      })
    }
    
  }, [])

  async function signIn({ email, password }: SignInProps) {
    try {

      const response = await api.post('/session', {
        email,
        password
      })
      
      console.log(response)

      const { id, name, token, role } = response.data

      setCookie(undefined, '@proposalsmayarabecker.token', token, {
        maxAge: 60*60*24*30,
        path: "/"
      })

      setUser({
        id,
        name,
        email,
        role
      })
      
      api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
      
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
      
      toast.success(`Bem vindo(a), ${name}`)
      router.push("/")
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Erro ao fazer login: "  + error.response.data.message)
      console.log("Erro ao fazer login: ", error);
    }
  }

  async function signOut() {
    try {
      destroyCookie(undefined, '@proposalsmayarabecker.token')
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
      router.replace("/login")
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Erro ao fazer logout")
      console.log("Erro ao tentar deslogar")
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isAuthenticated, signIn, signOut }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

My repo is: https://bitbucket.org/eltin182/proposals-mayarabecker-dev/
I have been separated in backend and frontend and it's better, I think.